# Display taxonomy terms differently by content type

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

Is there any way to display the taxonomy terms slightly differently depending on the content type they appear in? For instance, I have two content types that I'd like to have use the same vocabulary, but the terms represent slightly different things to end users.

Example: a node field asks an organization "how are you interested in connecting with a campus?" and answers include "lead an interactive workshop" and "participate on a panel". When a different content type asks a teacher "how are you interested in organizations connecting with you?" the answers include "have an organization lead a workshop" and "host a panel". Obviously those answers correspond 1:1, so I'd like to use the same vocabulary. But they need to present themselves slightly differently in each content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since vocabularies are linked to nodes via fields you'd be best off handling this in `hook_preprocess_node()` in your theme file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];

  // Only make the change if this is a certain node type
  if ($node->type == 'my_type') {
    // Extract the term IDs from the field
    $tids = array();
    foreach ($node->field_vocab[$node->language] as $value) { 
      $tids[] = $value['tid'];
    }

    // This example adds the taxonomy terms to a simple list, you'll
    // want to replace this with whatever theme function you need
    $items = array();
    foreach (taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids) as $term) {
      $items[] = l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid");
    }

    // Replace field_vocab in the vars with the new content
    $vars['field_vocab'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
  }
}
```

That might need to be changed/added to depending on your needs but it should give you a place to start from. Once you've added the new hook to the template.php file make sure you clear Drupal's hooks so the registry will be updated.